# run windows home server 2011 64 bit as Guest on VMware intel d525mw

Tags: vmware

recently I bought an Intel mini-itx d525mw motherboard having as objective to set up Virtual Machines under VMWare Server5 to gather some knowledges. Installing unix based Servers on vmware I thought I should give a try with Windows Home Server 2011 as well. During the install process I had to realize that as Guest won't run on 64bit. Unfortunately the Processor doesn't support VT from Bios. Is there a way to get Home Server 2011 to work under VMWare Server? I would like to use it as File Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message said, you need a processor with hardware virtualization support. The Intel Atom D25 series processors which are included with these boards [do not have virtualization support](http://ark.intel.com/products/65470/Intel-Atom-Processor-D2550-%281M-Cache-1_86-GHz%29).

Only a very small subset of Intel Atom processors support virtualization. You will not be able to build an "embedded" virtualization server using an Atom unless you choose your processor carefully.

Comment: thanks for your feedback! I've been looking better around and as it seems there is no way to run on my configuration any type of 64bit V Machines.

Comment: @lgt Intel introduced some virtualization capable Atom processors in 2013. If you're still intent on doing this, maybe time to go shopping again. :)